# Getting error message on while AJAX-get on localhost with node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to use AJAX to get a piece of string from a local server made using `node.js`, the connection is being done, status 200, everything is working but I still can't get the piece of string. May someone provide me an explanation of why this is happening?

P.S.: I'm still a newbie to `node.js`

***`Node.js` server code:***

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
  response.end("var a = 'Hello World';");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

***`AJAX` Call code:***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
            async: 'false',
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            console.log('DONE: Request has been successfully sent');
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('ERR: Request failed \nSTATUS: '+textStatus+'\nERROR: '+errorThrown);
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Console:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

XHR failed loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/".send @ jquery-latest.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery-latest.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ 

ERR: Request failed 
STATUS: error
ERROR: 

Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}
```

Comment: Try wrapping your code in `$.ready()`

Comment: Yes, your `$.ajax` call

Comment: it's still giving the exact same outputs :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cross domain` often fails the ajax call because of `violation` of `same origin policy`. Therefore, you need to modify your code and remove `crossDomain : true,`.
Also, add a `timeout:5000,` or write `async: false,` for safe side.

It will work then.